# Uniqueness of Primitive of an integral

Tags: calculus

I know this is a stupid question. But I feel stuck to show this "trivial" fact.
Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an interval domain (which can be either bounded or unbounded) and $f \in C_{c}(I)$ such that $\int_{I}f=0$. I want to show that the primitive of $f$ exists and unique.

For convenience, $C_{c}(I)$ is the space of continuous functions over $I$ with compact support.

The existence is not difficult to see by using the fact that $f$ is continuous and therefore by fundamental theorem of calculus, we obtain $F$ as the primitive of $f$. Moreover, if another primitive $G$ exists, then $\forall x \in I, F(x)-G(x)= C$ (constant). Now, my problem is I want to show that $C = 0$ by using $\int_{I}f=0$ but it seems like I have technical difficulties.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you very much and I am sorry for asking such petty trivial question!

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood what you are trying to prove. Once you have one primitive $F$ you have them all by adding a constant.  The fact that the integral of $f$ is $0$ doesn't make the primitive unique.

Comment: Actually I am trying to prove Lemma 8.1 in Ham Brezis book and there is a line that such function has a (unique) primitive with compact support. That is why I want to show that the primitive satisfying $\int_{I}f= 0$ is unique.

Comment: Take the primitive $F$ with $F(a) = 0$ where $f(x) = 0$ for $x < a$, and note that $F(b) = 0$ if $f(x) = 0$ for $x > b$.  Then $F$ is in $C_c(I)$, but no other primitive of $f$ is.

Comment: If the interval is bounded then everything has compact support. If the interval is unbounded and $F$ has compact support then $F + c$ won't have compact support, so a primitive with compact support is unique if one exists. That's easy to prove.

Comment: Thanks! It helps a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. You can answer your own question so that it doesn't remain on the unanswered queue attracting attention.

Answer (score 1):

By our assumption, $F \in C_{c}(I)$ and thus there exists an interval $[a,b]$ such that $F\equiv 0$ in $\mathbb{R}\backslash[a,b]$. However, if there exists another primitive $G$, then we can (by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus) set $F(x) = G(x) + C$ for any $x \in I$. This implies $G(x) = -C$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}\backslash[a,b]$. Therefore $C$ must be zero to have a compact support.